# Illegal modifier for the interface method

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, interface

I have this code:

```
public interface Type {
    public static Type match(String string) {
        try {
            return TypeBuiltIn.valueOf(string.toUpperCase());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I was doing the same thing as some guy in the tutorial, for him it works fine, but I get an error on `match(String string)`:

> Illegal modifier for the interface method match; only public & abstract are permitted

I tried to remove the static, but nothing works. It says I should remove the method body, but what do I do then?

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: I do not know much of Java, but maybe you should change the type to something else other than public because you are using return?

Comment: Make sure you are compiling with Java 8.

Comment: `interface` methods marked `static` haven't always been allowed. Compile with Java 8.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't catch just Exception, that's never good practice. I think you need to catch EnumConstantNotFound in your case.

Comment: You need to be using Eclipse Luna (4.4) or Eclipse Mars (4.5) to get full support for Java 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a Java version below **Java 8**, this code would not work because `interface` does not support static methods for `java` versions below **Java 8**. You need to update your Java version from [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), and edit your environment variable `path` from your system settings.

If you don't intend to update your *java version* then your `Interface` would not support any static method. You have to `implement interfacename` for the `class` and have the particular body inside the static method within a class.

For that, your interface should look as below:

```
public interface Type {
    public abstract Type match(String string);
}
```

And you `class` should be as below:

```
public class YourDesiredClassname implements Type {

    public static Type match(String string) {
        try {
            return TypeBuiltIn.valueOf(string.toUpperCase());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I already have Java 1.8.0_60, all system variables are ok, but it still doesn't work... There's the same error.

Answer (score 1):

please see the output of command **java -version**. The first line it prints should be something like

```
java version "1.8.xxxx"
```

Static methods default implementation is not allowed before java 8.

Comment: I have java 1.8.0_60 installed, but when I go to Window -> Preperences -> Java -> Compiler, the Compiler compliance levels are from 1.3 to 1.7, I can't choose 1.8! :O

Comment: @2xxx2 That's not how you edit your **Java** compiler. Do as I say. Goto _Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables... -> Create New Variable for User._ `Variable name = "Path"` (without quotation) `Variable value = "path of your bin folder where java jdk 1.8.0_60 is installed"` (again, without quotation)

Comment: I know, it was set to the 1.8.0_60's bin folder but it didn't work. But it's ok now, I fixed it. Thanks anyway. :P

Answer (score 1):

Wow... You guys are amazing! Thank you all so much for the help, I tought I would get one answer in about a week, but I got 7 in a few hours. I was using Kepler so it didnt work, but then I installed Java 8 Support and it works.

If someone has the same problem, here's the page for Java 8 Support:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

Thanks everyone for helping. :)

Comment: greg-449 said that only Luna and Mars support Java 8 so I googled a fix for Kepler and that's where I found it... Thanks, Greg! :P